# Select rows with same id but different value in another column in a table

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have above table having a same **ITEM_ID** but **SERIAL_NO** is different and **DATE** is also different some time but when i m using following query i got an output such as follows

```
SELECT ITEM_ID
     , SUPPLIER_ID
     , DATE
     , GROUP_CONCAT( SERIAL_NO ) AS SERIAL_NO     
  FROM purchase_mst 
 GROUP 
    BY ITEM_ID
```

[image]

the last **SERIAL_NO** is **ADN SD]55** is on date 24-06-2017 but having display in 23-06-2017 and **ITEM_ID** is 1 but i want to display it in 24-06-2017 not in 23-06-2017

Comment: Try to use ORDER BY `DATE` DESC

Comment: after GROUP BY ITEM_ID or before it, please help me to how to write it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp Group, then order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add one more group in query

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUPPLIER_ID, DATE, GROUP_CONCAT( SERIAL_NO ) AS SERIAL_NO FROM purchase_mst GROUP BY ITEM_ID, DATE
```